# Hyperledger Fabric - Detection of Modification to StateDB in Peer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

**This is a question about StateDB automatic fix after tampering.**

We're wondering if manipulation to StateDB (CouchDB) could be detected and fixed automatically by peer.
The following documents states there is a a state reconciliation process synchronizing world state in Peer.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/gossip.html#gossip-messaging

> In addition to the automatic forwarding of received messages, a state
> reconciliation process synchronizes world state across peers on each
> channel. Each peer continually pulls blocks from other peers on the
> channel, in order to repair its own state if discrepancies are
> identified.

But when we test it as follows:

> ```
> Step 4: modify value of key a in StateDB
> Step 10: Wait for 15 minutes
> Step 11: Create a new block
> Step 12: Check value of a through chaincode and confirm it in StateDB directly
> ```

[image]
The tampered value is not fixed automatically by peer.
Can you help clarify the meaning of "state reconciliation process" in the above document and if peer would fix the tampering to StateDB.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Gossip protocol is to sync up legit data among peers, not tampered data in my view. What is legit data? Data whose computed hash at anypoint of time matches with the orignally computed hash, which will not be the case for the tampered data, and so I'd not expect Gossip protocol to sync such 'dirty data'. This defeats the purpose of Blockchain altogether as a technology, and hence this is a wrong test to be performed in my view.

Now, then what is Gossip protocol? Refer https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/gossip.html#gossip-protocol

> "Peers affected by delays, network partitions, or other causes
> resulting in missed blocks will eventually be synced up to the current
> ledger state by contacting peers in possession of these missing
> blocks."

So, in cases where the peer should have comitted a block to ledger and would have missed due to some reasons like the ones said above, 'Gossip' is only a fall back strategy for the HLF to reconcile the ledger among the peers.

Now in your test case, I see you are using 'query', now query does not go via the orderer to all the peers, it just goes to one peer and returns the value, you need to do a 'getStringState' as a 'transaction', for the 'enderosement' to run, and that is when would the endorsement fail citing the mismatch between the values for the same key among the peers is what I'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
    # Gossip state transfer related configuration
    state:
        # indicates whenever state transfer is enabled or not
        # default value is true, i.e. state transfer is active
        # and takes care to sync up missing blocks allowing
        # lagging peer to catch up to speed with rest network
        enabled: false
```

.......................................................................................................

```
        # the process of reconciliation is done in an endless loop, while in each iteration reconciler tries to
        # pull from the other peers the most recent missing blocks with a maximum batch size limitation.
        # reconcileBatchSize determines the maximum batch size of missing private data that will be reconciled in a
        # single iteration.
        reconcileBatchSize: 10
        # reconcileSleepInterval determines the time reconciler sleeps from end of an iteration until the beginning
        # of the next reconciliation iteration.
        reconcileSleepInterval: 1m
        # reconciliationEnabled is a flag that indicates whether private data reconciliation is enable or not.
        reconciliationEnabled: true
```

Link: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/sampleconfig/core.yaml

In addition to the automatic forwarding of received messages, a state reconciliation process synchronizes world state across peers on each channel. Each peer continually pulls blocks from other peers on the channel, in order to repair its own state if discrepancies are identified. Because fixed connectivity is not required to maintain gossip-based data dissemination, the process reliably provides data consistency and integrity to the shared ledger, including tolerance for **node crashes**.